# NAT a specific IP to go to ppp0 and others to go to eth0 coming from internal wifi interface

Tags: linux, firewall, vpn, nat

Basically I have a armbian distro configured as NAT where wlan0 is the internal interface and eth0 is the "pubic" interface that provides internet (this set is provided out of the box by armbian-config).

My devices connect over wlan0 grabbing an IP, say 172.24.1.114

I have added a VPN to a remote network resulting in the creation of ppp0, with IP 10.10.10.12

Having these info, what I want to achieve is:

- Only one IP (e.g. 172.24.1.114) has to always go towards ppp0 (that is all traffic back and forth should go to ppp0, so I can either reach machines and navigate on internet with the remote IP)
- All other IPs can normally go towards eth0

Starting from the configured NAT from armbian-config I have added the extra iptables rules:

```
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT (this is before -A FORWARD -i wlan0-o eth0 -j ACCEPT created by armbian-config)
-A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE (order shouldn't impact with -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE created by armbian-config)
-A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT (just to be sure!)
```

These extra rules + the one from armbian-config seem to work all most well:

```
From 172.24.1.114 client I can see content of a remote web server, say http://10.10.10.20 ( so apparently it goes thru ppp0)
From 172.24.1.114 client I can navigate on internet, but unfortunately checking the IP I go out with (using a geo ip website), it still results the one from eth0
All other clients correctly navigate going out thru eth0
```

So to summarize it, I can now reach the remote network over VPN for that IP but it is not able to navigate thru ppp0

As last try I found the way to set rule policies, like in this guide (http://wiki.wlug.org.nz/SourceBasedRouting), so I can specify that source IP 172.24.1.114 goes to custom table other than the main one; then I added in this new table the default gateway of 10.10.10.1 dev ppp0. This leads to lack of web navigation for that IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved all.
First the required iptables' rules are (these give access to the remote VPN's machines):

```
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Then, to indicate which IP or range of IPs have to have a different route, you need policy rules:

- open `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` and put your entry (ID tablename):

  ```
  100   my_custom_table
  ```
- `ip rule add from 172.24.1.114/24 table my_custom_table` (tells to go to another table other than the main one for the source IP 172.x.x.x)
- `ip route add 172.24.1.0/24 dev wlan0 table my_custom_table` (required to receive packets back from ppp0)
- `ip route add default via 10.10.10.1 dev ppp0 table my_custom_table` (routes packet to the VPN's gateway)

**Make sure the firewall on the VPN server allows incoming traffic from VPN IPs.**

Answer (score 0):

Creating an `ip rule` for that source address is the right approach.

To diagnose such problems, `tcpdump` is useful.

Can the VPN client itself access the internet through the VPN?

- If yes, you need to add NAT in the VPN client for your address.
- If not, you need to add NAT in the VPN server, and make sure it is not blocked.

Comment: Thanks for replying back...so first of all I have to say that I am using windows VPN built-in (just to state if there is some limitations here). If I change the default gw on the machine to be set to VPN gw, within the machine I go thru VPN gw when doing a traceroute. From a client that is on the WIFI interface, it is not able to do. This is what I don't understand.

Comment: so I created a rule for that IP: default via 10.10.10.1 dev ppp0 on custom table. If I sniff traffic with tcpdump on port 80, I see that trying to navigate on internet nothing is passing thru ppp0

Comment: What exactly are your rules and routes? Add them to the question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the previous hint. It seems to be the Firewall on Windows that blocked the request; now I can navigate thru the VPN although it seems to be not really stable!

Comment: Specifically, it seems I can navigate over fb messanger without problem, but not over whatsapp or web...